# Page Title loading before css

Tags: jquery, html, css, netsuite

I'm experiencing a glitch on page load.

The title is loading first its starts on the left hand side of the page(my site is centered) and then moves to the correct position once the page is fully loaded. Please refresh a couple of times to see what i'm referring to.

I tried to use inline styles to make it start correctly but its not working -- i'm using an ERP system netsuite which is one of the reasons why i'm having trouble.

Any ideas on how i can fix this?

[image]

Comment: I'm using Chrome on a Mac Book Pro and I don't see any issues with the link you provided. It sounds more like an issue with dynamic content (where the width of the container is changing as content is loaded/created) rather than CSS being loaded before the HTML elements.

Comment: go through other pages of the site you will eventually see what i'm referring to.

Comment: are you positioning anything using jQuery or is everything done by CSS?

Comment: everything is with css.

Comment: @Phreak I've gone through the other pages and the title is loading fine. Perhaps post a screenshot? I've tested in Chrome, IE8-10, Firefox

Comment: its happening to fast to screenshot-- WAIT I got the screen shot

Comment: The picture has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS arranges everything before and Javascript loads. Your Javascript fixes the display AFTER the page is loaded and displayed, so you need to fix your CSS

It appears that in your HTML you have set for the DIV containing "40% off Gluten-Free Lunches and Snacks" has it's margins defined there as 0px, which would make it not centered.

Line 247 when you view source in your HTML:

`<div id='div__body' style="margin: 0px;  margin-top: 3px;">`

This overrides any CSS you have in your CSS files. You need to change that to margin: auto; to center that div before and Javascript manually positions the div.

PS: if you are using javascript to position things it may not be neccessary as you should be able to do most things with raw CSS.

Comment: <div id="div__title" style="margin: 0px;"></div> i see that but i'm not even using that div

Comment: should be 2 lines below the line that you quoted. I'm using chrome and it shows as line 247 in `view-source:http://www.gopicnic.com/s.nl/sc.39/category.14672/.f#.VIe3hDHF9-4`

here's a bigger exerpt
`<div id='div__title' style='margin: 0px;'></div>

<div id='div__label' class='scrollarea' style='margin: 0px; overflow:hidden;'></div>

<div id='div__body' style="margin: 0px;  margin-top: 3px;">
<table border='0' ...

Comment: <div id="div__body" class="container"> is all i see i'm using chrome as well.

Comment: Okay you were correct the site was appying classes with jquery i was unaware of this. This led me to apply the class it was adding which resolved the glitch thanks for yours/everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

On line 440-ish (depending on your prettifier) of [NLUtil.jsp__NS_VER=2014.2.0](http://www.gopicnic.com/javascript/NLUtil.jsp__NS_VER=2014.2.0&minver=111&locale=en_US.nlqs) (in the function `resetDivSizes`) you are changing the width of the "div__body" DIV dynamically, which may be the culprit here.

Comment: I think that's a built in netsuite script i'm not entirely sure if i'm even able to modify that.